# How do I just get the image, and get rid of the black columns on right and left in Shotwell?

Tags: image-processing, shotwell

Is there a way of cropping the image in the center and getting rid of the black columns that shotwell shows on the screen?

Comment: Clarify your question

Comment: I can crop the photo, but what then? What I'm trying to do is view the images the way you might look at a series or photos that you took on holiday.  GIMP is worse... but that's pretty evident!

Comment: Is it possible that you only see black boxes on the sides because the images you're trying to view aren't the same resolution than your screen - i.e. viewing 4:3 images on a 16:9 screen?

Comment: Post exactly what you want in your question instead of in the comment so people can learn what your specific question/concern actually is.

Answer (score 1):

From command line you can use this

```
convert {image} -bordercolor black -border 1x1 -fuzz 20% -trim +repage {new_image}
```

From the imagemagick manual: [trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim) and the [commandline options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim):

> **Trim, the 'Auto-Crop' Operator**
>
> The "-trim" operator is a very close relation to the highly versatile "-crop" operator discussed above. However instead of supplying an argument, this operator attempts to remove any borders or edges of an image which did does not change in color or transparency. In other words it removes the 'boring' bits surrounding an image.
>
> Use a `+repage` to remove the virtual canvas page information if it is unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the image. Click the "Crop" button. Crop the image to the desired format. Click "Crop" when done.

Comment: I'll end w/ a crop.  I may have tried that; I'll double check.